# How to host an own chess ICS server?

Tags: engines

I want to host my own chess server (just in my home network, nothing public) to play chess with some friends.

I did some research on it and found out that the protocol used to realize a chess server is called - like the server - ICS.
The results I've found were very vague, most of them point to the existing big hosters like freechess.org, chess.com etc.

Are there any tools to host an own chess server?

Comment: I have not done this before (I am in the process of setting it up now) but the lichess source code is available publically. If you go look here https://github.com/ornicar/lila/wiki/Lichess-Development-Onboarding , you might be able to setup a local server with lichess.

Comment: @chackerian Hey, thanks ;) I'll check that out.

Comment: That should work if you get it setup. Someone just told me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup lichess locally with this guide: [github.com/ornicar/lila/wiki/Lichess-Development-Onboarding](http://github.com/ornicar/lila/wiki/Lichess-Development-Onboarding). The creator of lichess said this should work over irc.

Comment: Probably even lichess.org "Play with friends" serves my purposes... + 1 for pointing out lichess.org exists ;)

Comment: I thought you were looking for a way of hosting your own service. Yeah lichess and chess.com and ICC probably all have play with friend like functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way of hosting an own service - you're right and thank you for your answer. I just found out that probably my reasons for hosting an on server have become obsolete - which doesn't change anything on the correctness of your answer though. Hope I could solve this mistake ;)